# Parallel and sequencial script execution

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, debian

Need to run the following: if script-a ok, run script -b and script-c in parallel.

Tried the following code, but it runs script-a && script-b and script-c in parallel.

```
script-a && script-b & script-c & wait
```

Is there a way to group script-b and script-c?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use braces:

```
script-a && { script-b & script-c & wait; }
```